# In MATLAB, how do I scan my .txt files for numbers to put in an array?

Tags: arrays, matlab, scanf

I am having trouble trying to get the information from my .txt file to MATLAB into an array so I can process the data. Here is my current code

```
fileID = fopen(filename,'r');%assume filename is a generic name for my file

sizeData = [256 inf];
formatSpec = '%f';
OriginalData = fscanf(fileID,formatSpec,sizaData); %OriginalData is the array
```

My .txt file looks something like this...

[image: Picture of txt file]

The size of the information is 256 x 256 array. I can't quite figure out why my OriginalData array is showing nothing. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I'm lazy, probably would just do ` t = readtable('myfile.csv','HeaderLines',31);` And then make a matrix out of the table with `table2array`

Comment: If you want to import with scanf, you gotta get over the headerlines I think... either make a new .txt with header deleted or read off some lines before you pass it to fscanf

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a bunch of text first followed by the numeric data.  Reading this data as is won't work because your format specifiers are expecting floating point numbers at the very beginning of your text file, yet you have a bunch of text that isn't floating point data instead.

Skip the text first then read in the data after the text.  Try doing:

```
OriginalData = dlmread(filename, ' ', 31, 0);
```

[`dlmread`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dlmread.html) reads numeric text data from a file and imports it into MATLAB.  The first parameter is the file you want to read, the second is the delimiter that separates numbers, which is the space for your case, then we want to skip over 31 rows, and have a no column offset - denoted by the third and fourth parameters respectively.